# Add image over text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add an image over some text that I have. This is similar to retailmenot.com's reveal coupon code. When a user clicks on the image the image is removed and reveals the text underneath while simultaneously linking the user to an external url.

The base layer can be as follows:

```html
<div class="base">
    <h3>Some text</h3>
</div>
```

I want to load an image with the following over it when the text is clicked:

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg"/>
</div>
```

The height of the base layer with class "base" is variable, so the image has to be resized to fit it. I have a working example where I place the image and then resize it, but this creates issues when javascript may not be enabled as the image fails to be resized and looks messy. I want the script to fall back to just showing the underlying text if javascript is disabled.

How can I add and automatically resize such an overlay on page load using jquery or javascript?

Comment: do you want the class names to be different after placing image or what?

Comment: did you try examining how the html is structured in site you want to mimic? Concept is not difficult using mostly css

Comment: I would want the same css names

Comment: thats great... wait a moment for my answer

Comment: Sorry for delay... my answer is already posed @user2694306...

Answer (score 0):

Let your `html` page has this following code

```html
<div class="base">
</div>
```

Don't place any code about your image in html page. And then in your `jQuery` code.

```js
var img = '<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg"/>';
var txt = 'Some text';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).find('.base').html(txt).show();
    $(this).find('.base').click(function(){
        if($(this).html() == img)
            $(this).html(txt).show();
        else
            $(this).html(img).show();
    });
});
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: Will this replace the html or just add 'content' for the time being. When a user clicks the image it will be removed, so I just want to make sure this is feasible in this situation.

Comment: @user2694306 you didn't mention about click operation in your question. Okay. Do you want to change the content from text to image and vice-versa when user clicks on the content of class `base`??

Comment: Exactly, it should turn to the image automatically and then toggle off, but never back on once off

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Set overlay position and dimension to same as base
    $base = $(".base");
    $overlay = $(".overlay");
    $overlay.offset($base.offset());
    $overlay.height($base.outerHeight());
    $overlay.width($base.outerWidth());

    $overlay.show();

    //Hide overlay on click (show hidden text)
    $(".overlay").click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

and with css:

```
.overlay{
/* Hide overlay if no js */
    position: absolute;
    display: none;    
}
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqu80rjr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can have the overlay in the base, as such:

```
<div class="base">
    <h3>Some text</h3>
    <div class="overlay">
        <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can css this, no need for javascript:

```
.base{
    position: relateive;
}
.overlay{
    position: absolute; /* or fixed if scrollbars involved */
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
 /* or replace right and bottom with: */
 /* width: 100%;
    height: 100%; */
}
```

You can now use javascript to toggle visibility:

```
$('.overlay').fadeIn();
```